# Redshift/Postgres between function produces seemingly unrelated error when ">" or "<" both work but not together

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift, between, digits

I am trying to filter out data that is stored as strings but represents numeric values.
I filter out non-numeric strings then convert to a float.  I am then trying to filter values above or below a specific amount.  Below is a simplified version of my query that works with the filters disabled

```
WITH attributes AS (

    SELECT
        property_id,
        CASE WHEN regexp_replace(value, '[^0-9.]', '')='' THEN
            null
        WHEN regexp_replace(value, '[^0-9.]', '') = '.' THEN NULL
        ELSE
            regexp_replace(value, '[^0-9.]', '')::float
        END AS sqft, 'platform' FROM mv_prop_attributes
        WHERE
            display_name = 'Livable Area'
            and sqft is not null
            and length(sqft)>0
)

    SELECT
            *
        FROM
            attributes
        WHERE true
--          and sqft < 100000 --works
--          and sqft>200 --works
--          and sqft < 100000 and sqft>200 --does not work
--          and sqft between 200 and 100000 --does not work
```

### As noted in the commented portions I can filter above or below a value but not a range.  Attempts to do so produce the following error:
ERROR:  Invalid digit, Value '.', Pos 0, Type: Double
DETAIL:

### error:  Invalid digit, Value '.', Pos 0, Type: Double
code:      1207
context:   .
query:     438646641
location:  :0
process:   query0_117_438646641 [pid=0]

This is running on an up to date redshift cluster.  Thank you for any suggestions on how to resolve this at the DB level.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is likely that you didn't account for a period (vs. a decimal point).  The string "one thousand square feet." would come through your SQL as a single '.' which cannot be converted to a float.

I suspect that you aren't getting the error with inequality as Redshift can push down WHERE clauses where it can (but this case seems extreme).  Inequality can be applied to string - '1' < '2' - but this doesn't work the same for ranges.  This could be letting the query run but is a long shot.

==================================================================

A way to test if the source data has extra '.'s in it would be to run:

```
SELECT count(1) 
FROM mv_prop_attributes
WHERE value like '%.%.%';
```